How to fix Error in EDC connector: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/edc/spi/system/injection/Injector
I am trying to add an Identity Provider to transfer sample of the Eclipse data space components connector. However I face some troubles while trying to run the connector. I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/edc/spi/system/injection/Injector
        at org.eclipse.edc.boot.system.runtime.BaseRuntime.<init>(BaseRuntime.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.edc.boot.system.runtime.BaseRuntime.<init>(BaseRuntime.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.edc.boot.system.runtime.BaseRuntime.main(BaseRuntime.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.edc.spi.system.injection.Injector
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 3 more

this is my build gradle file of the connector:

plugins {
    `java-library`
    id("application")
    alias(libs.plugins.shadow)
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.edc.connector.core)
    implementation(libs.edc.boot)
    implementation(libs.edc.control.plane.api.client)
    implementation(libs.edc.control.plane.api)
    implementation(libs.edc.control.plane.core)
    implementation(libs.edc.dsp)
    implementation(libs.edc.configuration.filesystem)
    implementation(libs.edc.vault.filesystem)

    implementation(libs.edc.management.api)
    implementation(libs.edc.transfer.data.plane)
    implementation(libs.edc.transfer.pull.http.receiver)

    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.selector.api)
    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.selector.core)

    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.control.api)
    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.public.api)
    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.core)
    implementation(libs.edc.data.plane.http)
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32")
    runtimeOnly("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32")
    implementation(project(":policy:policy-01-policy-enforcement:policy-functions"))
    implementation(project(":transfer:IdentityProvider"))
}

application {
    mainClass.set("org.eclipse.edc.boot.system.runtime.BaseRuntime")
}

var distTar = tasks.getByName("distTar")
var distZip = tasks.getByName("distZip")

tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    archiveFileName.set("connector.jar")
    dependsOn(distTar, distZip)

}


can anybody see my mistake?
